# Custom authorizer not called

Tags: ember-cli, ember-simple-auth

I'm trying to implement a custom authorizer (using ember-cli and ember-cli-simple-auth) but the `authorize` method is not being called on any requests.  The `init` function is being called and the message that appears in the console when there is no authorizer registered is no longer showing up.  Here is the initializer code:

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import Base from 'simple-auth/authorizers/base';
import ENV from '../config/environment';

ENV['simple-auth'] = ENV['simple-auth'] || {};
ENV['simple-auth'].authorizer = 'authorizer:custom';
ENV['simple-auth'].crossOriginWhiteList = [ENV.NET.API_ENDPOINT];

var CustomAuthorizer = Base.extend({
    init: function () {
        console.log('Intialize authorizer');
    },
    authorize: function(jqXHR, requestOptions) {
        console.log('Authorize');
        var token = this.get('session.token');
        if(this.get('session.isAuthenticated') && !Ember.isEmpty(token)) {
            authValue = "Token " + token;
            jqXHR.setRequestHeader('Authorization', authValue);
        }
    }
});

export default {
    name: 'authorization',
    before: 'simple-auth',
    initialize: function(container, application) {
        console.log('Registered');
        container.register('authorizer:custom', CustomAuthorizer);
    }
};
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem here was something quite dumb: my casing of `crossOriginWhitelist` was incorrect.

Comment: Hi Alex, are you sure it was because of that? I have the same problem but no way...

Comment: @masciugo Yeah, fortunately, it was a simple capital L that was causing the issues.  If you'd like to start a new question and link to it I'll take a look.

Comment: [Solved](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26803347/626341), thanks. So hard to debug JS apps..